# Twilio Error: 12200 Schema validation error, Invalid content was found starting with element 'Stream'. One of '{Play

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am encountering an error from Twilio and would appreciate assistance as there is limited information on the documentation page, and the error itself is not well-detailed.

> 12200 Schema validation, line: 2, warning Description Invalid content was found starting with element 'Message'. One of '{Play

The Twiml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Stream name="Feature tagging Audio Stream" track="outbound_track" url="wss://test.com/ws" status="started">
      <Parameter name="scheduled_meeting_id" value="room_name"/>
      <Parameter name="call_type" value="spec"/>
      <Parameter name="category" value="internal"/>
      <Parameter name="token" value="speech_to_text_token"/>
  </Stream>
  <Connect>
    <Room participantIdentity="Some (AI Bot)">room_name</Room>
  </Connect>
</Response>
```

I opted not to use the `<Start>` verb to ensure synchronous connection. However, when I include the verb, my connection is lost within 1ms. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio Support Engineer here. Please note that `<Stream>` is a noun and not a verb, hence it cannot be used as a child element of `<Response>`.

If the use case is to stream the audio to a websocket server while asynchronously connecting the call to a Programmable Video room, you would need to use the  verb with the  noun. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Start>
      <Stream name="Feature tagging Audio Stream" track="outbound_track" url="wss://test.com/ws" status="started">
         <Parameter name="scheduled_meeting_id" value="room_name" />
         <Parameter name="call_type" value="spec" />
         <Parameter name="category" value="internal" />
         <Parameter name="token" value="speech_to_text_token" />
      </Stream>
   </Start>
   <Connect>
      <Room participantIdentity="Some (AI Bot)">room_name</Room>
   </Connect>
</Response>
```